# How can I create a function which accepts any type?

Tags: rust

How can I create a function in Rust which accepts any type or more than one type as function argument?

My first approach :

```
fn multiple_types(argument : _) {
    println!("{}",argument);
}
```

I tried the type placeholder "_" as argument but this is not allowed...

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/generics.html#generic-functions

Comment: @TM90: you will have to learn about *bounds* (in this case, `std::fmt::Display`) for Rust will only accept to print your argument if you statically guarantee that it is printable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/generics.html#generic-functions):

> We can write functions that take generic types with a similar syntax:
>
> ```
> fn takes_anything<T>(x: T) {
>     // do something with x
> }
> ```